# PostgreSQL function returning public table based on a private table

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, supabase

I'm new to SQL. Can someone tell why this doesn't work and what to do to fix it? What I want is basically create a public table based on the values from a private one. Thank you very much in advance! :)

```sql
create or replace function get_random_prices()
returns table (item_id int, value int)
as $$
declare
    random_prices table (item_id int, value int);
begin
    select id, floor(random() * (max_value - min_value + 1) + min_value)
    insert into random_prices  
    as item_id, value 
    from prices_ranges; -- private table, no policies set
    return random_prices;
end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: There are multiple issues with this. Rather then step through them I will point you at [plgsql return](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) and point you at the `RETURN QUERY` example. Search the page for `CREATE FUNCTION get_available_flightid ...`.

Comment: Why don't you create a VIEW instead?

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of syntax errors in your function, you can try the similar code below:

```
create or replace function get_random_prices()
returns table (item_id int, value int)
language plpgsql
as $$
begin
    return query
    select
      id::int as item_id, 
      floor(random() * (max_value - min_value + 1) + min_value)::int as value
    from prices_ranges;
end;
$$
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It doesn't solve the problem though, it still cannot be accessed, it's private.

Comment: @szachy313, you are going to have to define what you mean by `private`? **Add as update to your question.**